# WPF Custom DateTimeFormat definitions in Culture

Tags: wpf, datetime, format, culture

I've been having problems with the stringformat of DateTime in my WPF application. I implemented the *The Internationalization Fix* which I found here: http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf as well as in several different StackOverflow questions.

This works great for culture/locale specific DateTime stringformats. However, when I do custom changes to the datetimeformat in the culture like so:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
ci.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = ".";
```

It's completely ignored in some controls, for example: DataGrid. While in others such as RichTextBox and DatePicker it works fine. Here's my OnStartup method in App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set CultureInfo
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");

        ci.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = ".";

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(FrameworkElement),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes that looks like a pretty nasty workaround. I'd be afraid of other side-effects it might have, particularly when dealing with date and time controls. Why not use a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) instead?

Comment: I'm pretty new to .NET so I wasn't even aware of IValueConverter. I'll start looking into it and see if I can solve my problem with that, and yeah I agree. Looks scary! Thanks!

Comment: Value converters are like a swiss army knife for data binding. Once you have a couple of them there's practically nothing you can't do when it comes to transforming data bound values (in either direction).

Comment: Yeah, I just got that realization when I was reading through the MSDN page. "Why didn't I know about this before!?". It works like a charm, thanks a bunch! And I can now remove workaround. Thanks again!